# Nested for loop + formatting multiple lists

Tags: python

Here is the code so far
Notes regarding the variables:
`'ports'` - there could be any number of ports in the 'ports' list
`'nodes_u'` this will contain any number of server names and IP address pairs
`'serv_name_u'` could be anything but is static once defined
`'port_qty'` is equal to the number of ports listed in 'ports'

```
ports = ['443', '80']
nodes_u = ['SERVER1', '10.0.0.1', 'SERVER2', '10.0.0.2']
serv_name_u = "TESTING"
port_qty = 2

for i in range(0, len(ports)):
    print("ltm pool "+serv_name_u+"_{0}_pool {{ \n    members {{"
          .format(ports[i]))
    for i in range(0, len(nodes_u), 2):
        print("        {0} {{ \n            address {1} \n        }}"
              .format(nodes_u[i], nodes_u[i+1]))
```

Here is an example of the output

```
ltm pool TESTING_443_pool { 
    members {
        SERVER1 { 
            address 10.0.0.1 
        }
        SERVER2 { 
            address 10.0.0.2 
        }
ltm pool TESTING_80_pool { 
    members {
        SERVER1 { 
            address 10.0.0.1 
        }
        SERVER2 { 
            address 10.0.0.2 
        }
```

My question or what I am trying to figure out is how I can get the port number displayed after the server name in the pool section only! so the output is like this e.g.

```
ltm pool TESTING_443_pool { 
    members {
        SERVER1:443 { <<<Port Number Here!
            address 10.0.0.1 
        }
        SERVER2:443 { <<<Port Number Here!
            address 10.0.0.2 
        }
ltm pool TESTING_80_pool { 
    members {
        SERVER1:80 { <<<Port Number Here!
            address 10.0.0.1 
        }
        SERVER2:80 { <<<Port Number Here!
            address 10.0.0.2 
        }
```

Every time I try something I just end up with both ports listed or the iteration jumps past the index range for the 'ports' list. Also if there is a better way to capture the input or generate the output I am all ears!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then come back and rephrase your question

Comment: Nice response to the feedback :) Is there a reason you're building these strings in such a disjointed way? Is the issue that you want the particular indentation levels on the printed output?

Comment: yeah essentially I am trying to write a small script that outputs code that can be pasted into an F5 load balancer. There is probably an API for the F5 but I havent got that advanced yet! :) anyways there is a specific syntax that it expects and that is the output I am trying to produce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the nested `for`-loop and just include both print statements in the outer `for`-loop, with the `port` number inserted at index `:{1}`:

```
for i in range(0, len(ports)):
    print("ltm pool "+serv_name_u+"_{0}_pool {{ \n    members {{"
          .format(ports[i]))
    # for i in range(0, len(nodes_u), 2):
    print("        {0}:{1} {{ \n            address {2} \n        }}"
          .format(nodes_u[i], ports[i], nodes_u[i+1]))
```

Output:

```
List of nodes:
ltm node SERVER1 { 
    address 10.0.0.1 
    }
ltm node SERVER2 { 
    address 10.0.0.2 
    }
ltm pool TESTING_443_pool { 
    members {
        SERVER1:443 { 
            address 10.0.0.1 
        }
ltm pool TESTING_80_pool { 
    members {
        10.0.0.1:80 { 
            address SERVER2 
        }
```

**Attempt #2**:
Using different incrementer names (`i` and `j`) in the nested `for`-loops to differentiate between the two lists may get the desired output:

```
for i in range(0, len(ports)):
    print("ltm pool "+serv_name_u+"_{0}_pool {{ \n    members {{"
          .format(ports[i]))
    for j in range(0, len(nodes_u), 2):
        print("        {0}:{1} {{ \n            address {2} \n        }}"
              .format(nodes_u[j], ports[i], nodes_u[j+1]))
```

Output:

```
ltm pool TESTING_443_pool { 
    members {
        SERVER1:443 { 
            address 10.0.0.1 
        }
        SERVER2:443 { 
            address 10.0.0.2 
        }
ltm pool TESTING_80_pool { 
    members {
        SERVER1:80 { 
            address 10.0.0.1 
        }
        SERVER2:80 { 
            address 10.0.0.2 
        }
```

As for a better way to capture the input or generate the output, consider using a different data structure for your inputs, like a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) with the `keys` as `name`, and `port`, and `values` as their respective `values`.

Comment: Almost but not quite! I tried that and got the same output as you, each pool should include both servers as members, Also if you look closely at the TESTING_80_pool instead of printing the name of the server it has printed the IP and then for the address it has printed the name of server. I believe this is to do with the step size of 2.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake, I used your second output as my target output instead of your first output example. Thanks for pointing that out! :) I'll try to correct it.

Comment: @Charles Crosland I think you were right, the problem seems similar to what you suggested, so I gave it another shot.

Comment: Thanks dude, I'll test it tomorrow and if it works (which it looks like it should) I'll validate this as the answer! Thanks for your help again...